# jquery click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a click event on an element that changes it's class from "fave" to "faved", I am then trying to fire a new clicked event if the element is clicked when it's class is faved, but it is not firing, here is my javascript.

```
$("#jobwall .fave").click(function(){
    var self =  $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/favourites/save_employer", 
        type: "POST",
        data: "employer_id="+self.attr('href'),
        success:function() {
            self.removeClass('fave');
            self.addClass('faved');
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$(".faved").live("click", function(){
    alert("!!");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What kind of HTML element has the id 'jobwall' ? It is important, because not all HTML elements allowed the onClick event.

Answer (score 5):

You may include the .click() event to the new object, and not to use .live().
Like this:

```
$("#jobwall .fave").click(function(){
    var self =  $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/favourites/save_employer", 
        type: "POST",
        data: "employer_id="+self.attr('href'),
        success:function() {
            self.removeClass('fave');
            self.addClass('faved');
            self.click(function(){alert("!!"); return false;});
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The .live() method is for adding elements, not changing. Remember this.

[More information about .live() here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Good luck :D

---

## Update

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

From the messing around I did it looks as if those `return false;` statements are getting in your way. You should really consider using `event.preventDefault();`... as such:

```
$("#jobwall .fave").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

[Check out this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ilmv/dH6Km/) for an example as to what I mean